# Setting up Mongolab on heroku for Meteor

Tags: mongodb, heroku, meteor, deployment, mlab

I am trying to set up my database on Mongolab/Heroku. According tot he Mongolab documentation, I should type:

`% mongo ds012345.mongolab.com:56789/dbname -u db_username -p pw!`

However, I am running into two issues:

1) I know where to get the dbname and db_username, but where do I get the pw? Is it the same pw as what I use to log into Heroku?

2) If i type in the command above, I get an error `-bash: mongo: command not found`

Can someone help?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: Additionally, I voted to close this question as off-topic since it is not related to programming (read *code*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) When you create a MongoLab add-on, it adds a `MONGOLAB_URI` environment variable to your Heroku app. More details here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab#getting-your-connection-uri

2) `mongo` refers to the mongo shell binary, which you'll need to install locally. It, along with all the other MongoDB binaries, can be downloaded here:

https://www.mongodb.org/downloads